# Generic method to export app data?

Tags: backup, data-synchronization, data, third-party, files.app

Is there currently a simple way to just access/export all data from an iPhone app to a MacBook computer?

I have been using a third part app for 5+ years in which I created a lot of data, mostly audio and video files. Unfortunately, it turns out the app doesn't have any sort of 'export' function and I can't access the data in the iOs Files app or in a simple way via my MacBook. I have not found any way to access the data from this third party app. I've tried iMazing, but it seems that the functionality of iMazing seems to have gotten very limited, correct? It seems to only allow me interact a few dedicated apps.

I've gotten to a point where I don't even care right now whether I can actually extract the data in a usable format. I would be glad if I can just back up the app in some way or another, to re-install at some later point (including the data) and deal with it later.

Is there any way to do any of this? It baffles me that I have so little control over the apps, or even just the data I've created on my iPhone.

Comment: If you USB connect to your Mac, does the app show anything in 'File Sharing'?

Comment: There are 3rd party iOS backup programs (iExplorer, iMazing) that may do this for you. I would investigate if either will do the job you need.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I'm not sure what you mean by 'File Sharing'. But if I click on my phone in Finder, and then click on 'Files' the app doesn't show up. Very few apps show up there. 7 out of the ~30 apps on my phone.

Comment: @SteveChambers: iMazing doesn't work. That's what I was talking about in my original post. iMazing is extremely limited now, probably due to some changes that Apple did at some point. It can only interact with very few apps - actually the same apps that already show up in Finder (see my comment to @Tetsujin).

Comment: So I guess there really might not be a generic way to access app data? Btw, iOS does actually acknowledge that it's "Documents and Data" and not the App itself. When I go to Settings/General/iPhone Storage and then click on the app, it shows me: App Size - X MB, Documents & Data - X GB

Comment: Like this… https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur0O1.jpg [showing an eBook reader as example] Not all apps do this, only some.